# Ambiguous parsing in the absence of prepositions

Tags: ambiguity, syntactic-analysis

Consider the following sentence which may appear, say, in a changelog of a website or an app:

> Order a taxi button on most pages.

1. Does it allow multiple parsings, i.e.

   - there is an entity named "a taxi button" that you can order from most pages;
   - on most pages there is a button that can be used to order a taxi.
2. If it does, which one is the more "natural"?
3. Is there a rule that would establish one of the parsings as primary and if there is, what is its name?
4. How do I search for another example of this kind? What are the common terms to be searched for if I want to find out more on this topic (read more examples, if nothing else)?
5. What if I change the sentence to "Taxi order button on most pages"? Does the problem persist, in particular, can the word "taxi" be read as a verb meaning "ship it somewhere using a taxi" now?

Comment: Order Taxi button on most pages. "Order a taxi" here functions like a name or title of the button. As such, it is an adjective describing the button. By using caps, the ambiguity is lifted. General idea: the title or name of an object.

Comment: 'Order' could also be interpreted as something from SQL...

Comment: "Order a taxi button on most pages" is, as a stand-alone sentence, utterly meaningless, because it has so many totally unrelated meanings.  Do you place a "taxi button" in some order?  Do you call the takeout place to order a "taxi button"?  Do you have to go to "most pages" and do this "ordering" on each one?  Are you looking for the "Order a taxi button" which appears on the most pages in the app?

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, this sentence does allow multiple parsings
2. Which one would be more natural would generally be indicated by context.

For example, if this were a changelog for a taxi website, I would read it as "There is a button to order a taxi on most pages". If it were a shopping site like Amazon, I would read it as "Order a button for taxis on most pages".

3. This is a job for punctuation. In this exact instance, containing the description within quotes would clarify it nicely:

> 'Order a taxi' button on most pages
>   Order a 'taxi button' on most pages
>   Order a taxi 'button on most' pages
>   Order a 'taxi' button on most pages

4. Search for "Ambiguous sentences in English".
5. "Taxi order button on most pages" is clearer, but could still be improved with quotes. However, I don't think most people would read the word Taxi as a verb there; they might read it as a button to order(as in request) a taxi, a button to show taxi order (as in sequence), a button to order(as in command) a taxi... etc.

However, **don't overthink it**. A lot of ambiguity is cleared up just by understanding the context.

Answer (score 0):

Broadly, you are interested in the topic of *ambiguity*. The example you have shows *syntactic ambiguity* rather than *lexical ambiguity* because the meaning differences are mostly due to different parses of the sentence, rather than different senses of the words.

Ambiguity is relevant to several sub-disciplines disciplines of linguistics (in decreasing order of relevance): semantics, psycholinguistics, and syntax. The answer to your question #2 would most likely be in psycholinguistics publications studying the role of lexical knowledge in disambiguation.

Here are two random resources that might serve as decent starting points.

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ambiguity/
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1207/s15516709cog2002_1/pdf